# (ReactJs) How do I add a phoneNumber to my firebase.auth() user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add a phone number to my user, without signing up by the phone number. I have an input that saves the input phoneNumber to this.state.phonenumber and I want to set this as the users phone number. How do I do this? I am getting the error, that:

> firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile has no property 'phoneNumber'.

Everything else is working fine.

```
signup = event =>{
    event.preventDefault();


        fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.signUpEmail, this.state.signUpPass).then((u) =>{
            var user = fire.auth().currentUser;
            user.updateProfile({
                displayName: this.state.fullName,
                phoneNumber: this.state.phonenumber,
            })
        }).catch((error) =>{
            alert(error)
        })

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you're written?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: The question describes my problem the best i can do. I want to assign a phone number to the user without signing up by phone number. So the user is signed up by email and password but also has a phone number

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do.  I'm asking if what you've written actually works the way you expect.  If not, please provide more details as to what you've observing that suggests it doesn't.  Is there an error?  What are you observing?

Comment: Oh ok, my apologies. It gives me an error, saying that firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile hast no property 'phoneNumber'. Everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to show the full details of the error.  There is an edit link at the bottom.  It's best not to bury information in comments.

Comment: okay, i will do that

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a `phoneNumber` as part of the user profile. Firebase Auth uses the phone number for sign in. You have 3 options:

1. Use the [admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) to set the phone number (but that means the user will be able to sign in with that phone number too) (not recommended).
2. Set the phone number as a custom claim via the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). (though the recommendation is to only save data that is used for access control in custom claims as they are propagated to the ID token payload).
3. Save phone number along with other additional user attributes (age, address, other user preferences) in a separate database (eg. RTDB, Firestore, etc) keyed by the user ID. (recommended solution)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try option 3